# Html List: From vertical to horizontal

Tags: html, css, wordpress, list

I have a social class provided by my WordPress theme as follows, and its placed [vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RILF.png):

```
<div class="social">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-twitter-alt"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-pinterest"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Iam trying to place this list in a horizontal line

```
display: inline!important;
```

But im stuck. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
.social ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

Comment: omg i missed the ```ul``` in css. Thank you;)

Answer (score 1):

Try below CSS.

```css
.social ul li{ display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="social">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">facebook<i class="ti-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">twitter<i class="ti-twitter-alt"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">linkedin<i class="ti-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">pinterest<i class="ti-pinterest"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```